# How can I get the target URL from buttons which may have different classnames?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to send logs of the buttons to analytics. A developer before me wrote this piece of code to target the button urls so he could later push them into an event_label. This isn't working anymore and I can't seem to find out why.

Here's the code:

```js
        let buttonURL = "URL unknown";

        if (e.target.attributes.onClick ) {
            buttonURL = e.target.attributes.onClick.value;
        } else if ( e.target.parentNode.action ) {
            buttonURL = e.target.parentNode.action;
        }
```

This is is put(with more data) into a getLabel function and pushed into the corresponding button log events.

I expected the target url to be the output but got 'URL unknown'

Comment: what is not working? Put a debugger in code and check it

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap/getNamedItem